# devise reset password token invalid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-recoverable

***controller***

```
def create
 # admin manually creates user
 UserMailer.reset_password_instructions(@user).deliver
end
```

***user.rb***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :generate_reset_password_token # generating devise reset token

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable and :omniauthable
  # :registerable,
  # :trackable,
  devise  :database_authenticatable,
          # :confirmable,
          :rememberable,
          :validatable,
          :recoverable,
          :trackable,
          :timeoutable


private

  # Generates a new random token for confirmation, and stores
  # the time this token is being generated
  def generate_reset_password_token
    raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(self.class, :reset_password_token)
    @raw_confirmation_token   = raw
    self.reset_password_token   = enc
    self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
  end

end
```

***user_mailer.rb***

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

   default from: 'no-reply@identt.co'

   def reset_password_instructions(resource, opts={})
    @resource = resource
    @token    = @resource.reset_password_token
    mail(to: @resource.email, subject: "Reset Password Instructions")
   end
end
```

***reset_password_instructions.html.erb***

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

At this point, when user is created manually by admin, `Password reset` Link is going to the email address, which I can see using `MailCatcher` or `letter_opener`.
http://lvh.me:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=6a8bc4683fc9e5dfcc789f94f9b6bd2b1c44fd857f13662d0f0d1f6212022f81

I click on the link and it successfully took me to 
edit password page. When I submit form, ivalidation failed with `Reset password token is invalid` message.

What am I missing here....

***UPDATE:***

**My Development.rb looks like:**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Configure letter opener to open email in browser
  # config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "lvh.me", :port => 1025 }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'lvh.me', port: 3000 }

  config.domain = 'lvh.me'
end
```

Comment: What does your development.rb looks like?

Comment: Remove `config.domain` and add `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }` See what happens. Restart server first.

Comment: Nope, that didn't solved my problem. `config.domain` is just a config variable I am using to set session in session_store, something like: `domain: Rails.configuration.domain`.

Comment: Whats your devise version?

Comment: ``devise version 3.5.1`` from Gemfile.lock

Comment: Have a read on this as somewhere in your user.rb doesnt look right: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.5.1/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L47

Comment: Try removing your method `generate_reset_password_token` and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a one line code for my solution, which I have made complicated by adding manual mailer, actions, etc.

To solve this problem I just have to call devise's `send_reset_password_instructions` in `user` object:

***In controller***

```
    @user.send_reset_password_instructions
```

Solved my problem.

**I cleaned up my code by removing (as per my question:)**

- `user_mailer.rb` file is no more required, so deleted it
- `views/user_mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb` file is not required, so deleted it.
- In `User.rb` model, remove `before_action :generate_reset_password_token` as well as `generate_reset_password_token` private method.
- Remove below mailer line from controller

  `UserMailer.reset_password_instructions(@user).deliver`

Answer (score 3):

I went crazy deep with this, and finally found the answer:

```
  def generate_reset_password_token
    raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(self.class, :reset_password_token)
    @raw_confirmation_token   = raw
    self.reset_password_token   = enc
    self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
  end
```

This code is right, you want the `user` to have `enc` as the `reset_password_token`. It's also good that you keep the `raw` variable handy.

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

   default from: 'no-reply@identt.co'

   def reset_password_instructions(resource, opts={})
    @resource = resource
    @token    = @resource.reset_password_token
    mail(to: @resource.email, subject: "Reset Password Instructions")
   end
end
```

For this part, you want `@token = @raw_confirmation_token` (`raw` from the token generator), not `@resource.reset_password_token` (which is `enc` from the generator).

I believe this solution is for devise 3.1+, it seems they changed their setup for added security, without explaining the two tokens.